# Problem checking checkbox status using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not very comfortable using javascript so trying my hands to use this in my one project,i have a small work which i have to impliment using javascript.
on my JSP page i need to display a list of items which checkbox against each item and need to track if user select a item or deselecting an item.
here is what i am trying

```
<input type="checkbox" value="someval" name="SelectedDestinationUUID" id="SelectedDestinationUUID" onchange="maintainCheckBoxStatus(this.value,'SelectedDestinationUUID')">
```

here is my javascript

```
function maintainCheckBoxStatus(checkBoxValue,checkBoxName){

    if(document.getElementById(checkBoxName).checked){
        alert("check");
        addCheckBoxStatus(checkBoxValue,true);
    }
    else{
        alert("check1");
        addCheckBoxStatus(checkBoxValue,false);
    }
}
```

now what happening is when i am selecting items it showing checked correctly but when unselecting the behaviour is something different
here are the details
let's suppose i have two items and i selected first than second and while deselecting i deselecting in the following order

1. deselecting item 1
2. deselecting item 2
   everything is working fine it showing checked and unchecked status fine.

but if I follow the following order for deselecting

1. deselecting item 2
2. deselecting item 1

Things got messed while deselcting item two the alert showing me that its status is selected.
can any one point me where i am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show addCheckBoxStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly please do

```
<input type="checkbox" value="someval" 
name="SelectedDestinationUUID" id="SelectedDestinationUUID" 
onchange="maintainCheckBoxStatus(this)">

function maintainCheckBoxStatus(checkBox){
    addCheckBoxStatus(checkBox.value,checkBox.checked);
}
```

which is the same as

```
<input type="checkbox" value="someval" 
name="SelectedDestinationUUID" id="SelectedDestinationUUID" 
onchange="addCheckBoxStatus(this.value,this.checked)">
```

Comment: that is known as hitting the bull eye..thanks.Though i am not in javascript (Java Developer) but want to know what exactly i was doing wrong so that i will not repeat this in future